# Como realizar consulta com alguns valores nulos?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

O `SQL` abaixo retorna os valores corretamente somente se o campo `data_emissao` estiver como **não nulo** na minha tabela do BD (independente se o parâmetro `cliente` foi passado ou não), porém desejo retornar os valores onde os campos `data_emissao` também estiverem **nulos** (caso o parâmetro `cliente` tenha sido passado).

Como devo utilizar o operador lógico `OR` sem deixar de obedecer a condição caso o campo `data_emissao` seja diferente de nulo?

```php
$sql  = " SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE :cliente OR :cliente_ IS NULL)";

$sql. = " AND (data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND data_emissao <= :dt_final 
OR :dt_final_ IS NULL)";
```

**Simulação do problema**:

```
------------------------------
-- Tabela `nfe`
------------------------------

1 | Aarco A | NULL
2 | Barco B | 13-01-2017
3 | Carco C | 14-01-2017
4 | Darco D | 14-01-2017
5 | Earco E | 15-01-2017
6 | Farco F | NULL
7 | Garco G | 16-01-2017
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')
```

Resultado obtido:

```
NULL | NULL | NULL
```

Resultado esperado:

```
1 | Aarco A | NULL
```

Eis aqui como a tabela foi criada:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for nfe
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nfe`;
CREATE TABLE `nfe` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_emissao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of nfe_teste
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('1', 'Aarco A', null);
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('2', 'Barco B', '13-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('3', 'Carco C', '14-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('4', 'Darco D', '14-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('5', 'Earco E', '15-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('6', 'Farco F', null);
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('7', 'Garco G', '16-01-2017');
```

SQL Fiddle do BD: [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/790cb5/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/790cb5/1)

Comment: SELECT * FROM nfe_teste WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NULL OR data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, ainda está retornando `NULL`.

Comment: Tente usar o operador OR
data_emissao IS NOT NULL OR data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')

Comment: Olá @olavooneto a consulta retornou todas as linhas da tabela.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> O SQL abaixo retorna os valores corretamente somente se o campo `data_emissao` estiver como **não nulo** na minha tabela do BD [independente se o parâmetro `cliente` foi passado ou não], porém desejo retornar os valores onde os campos `data_emissao` também estiverem **nulos** [caso o parâmetro `cliente` tenha sido passado].

Ou seja:

> Se o campo `data_emissao` estiver não nulo **OU** onde o campo `data_emissao` estiver nulo **E** o `cliente` tenha sido passado.

E portanto:

```
data_emissao IS NOT NULL OR (data_emissao IS NULL AND cliente IS NOT NULL)
```

Isso pode ser simplificado como:

```
data_emissao IS NOT NULL OR cliente IS NOT NULL
```

Uma prova disso é se olharmos os casos que você tem:

- `data_emissao` é nulo e `cliente` é nulo. - Não deve vir no resultado.
- `data_emissao` é nulo e `cliente` não é nulo. - Deve vir no resultado.
- `data_emissao` não é nulo e `cliente` é nulo. - Deve vir no resulado.
- `data_emissao` não é nulo e `cliente` não é nulo. - Deve vir no resulado.

O único caso que não interessa é quando os dois são nulos.

Entretanto, há mais duas restrições também:

1. As datas não nulas que importam são aquelas que são menores que a data informada (que pode ser nula).
2. Os clientes não-nulos que importam são aqueles que estão de acordo com o `LIKE`, se isto tiver sido informado.

A regra número 1 (que trás as datas de emissão não nulas que importam) fica assim:

```
data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND (data_emissao <= :data_final OR :data_final_ IS NULL)
```

Já a regra número 2 (que trás os clientes não nulos que importam) fica assim:

```
cliente IS NOT NULL AND (cliente LIKE :cliente OR :cliente_ IS NULL)
```

E portanto sua SQL fica assim:

```
SELECT * FROM nfe
WHERE (data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND (data_emissao <= :data_final OR :data_final_ IS NULL))
OR (cliente IS NOT NULL AND (cliente LIKE :cliente OR :cliente_ IS NULL))
```

Comment: Olá @VictorStafusa, excelente explicação. As duas regras estão corretíssimas, porém um detalhe que provavelmente não deixei claro é que, ao unir as duas, a que deverá prevalecer é a _segunda_, ou seja, ao realizar a consulta por `cliente` e um valor **não nulo** para `data_emissao`, os resultados deverão ser menores que a data estipulada e com base na palavra inserida (mesmo que na tabela do BD a `data_emissao` esteja nula).

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar UNION:

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.
>   Retirado do Manual ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html))

Esse comando combina dois resultsets em um, mas, não realiza Distinct, ou seja, se existirem linhas repetidas, elas vão aparecer.

Alterei seu conjunto de dados para incluir dois registros para o mesmo cliente, so que um contem a data e o outro não.

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for nfe
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `nfe`;
CREATE TABLE `nfe` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_emissao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of nfe_teste
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('1', 'Aarco A', null);
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('2', 'Barco B', '13-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('3', 'Carco C', '14-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('4', 'Darco D', '14-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('5', 'Earco E', '15-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('6', 'Farco F', null);
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('7', 'Garco G', '16-01-2017');
INSERT INTO `nfe` VALUES ('8', 'Aarco A', '13-01-2017');
```

A query final:

```
SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')
UNION 
SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NULL)
```

O resultado:

```
8 | Aarco A | 13-01-2017
1 | Aarco A | NULL
```

Para adequar ainda mais, você pode testar o parametro do nome do cliente antes de montar a instrução SQL para execução e executar apenas o SQL indicado. Algo como:

```
if(cliente != null)
{
   .sql = "SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')
UNION 
SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NULL)";
}
else
{
   .sql = "SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')
UNION 
SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (data_emissao IS NULL)";
}
```

**Edit: só vi depois que você pede para usar OR, então, desculpe ai. Se quiser eu retiro.**

Answer (score 2):

Alterei o nome das colunas para testar no meu ambiente, a `query` abaixo retornou o que você precisa:

```
SELECT * FROM #usuario WHERE (nome LIKE '%Aarco%')AND (data IS NULL or data <= '01-15-2017')
```

Comment: Olavo, novamente não funcionou. SQL Fiddle do meu BD: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/790cb5/1

Comment: SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE (cliente LIKE '%Aarco%')
AND (data_emissao IS NULL or data_emissao <= '15-01-2017')

Comment: Desta forma funcionou, testei no Sqlfiddle

Comment: Olá @olavooneto, pode publicar seu SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Segue link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/790cb5/2/0

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda Olavo. Sim, sua resposta resolve parte do meu problema, porém ainda não atende a situação inicial ["O SQL ... retorna os valores corretamente somente se o campo `data_emissao` estiver como não nulo na minha tabela do BD "], ou seja, preciso que a consulta também retorne os dados **não nulos** com base no intervalo de data especificado. @olavooneto

Comment: Você quer as linhas tanto do intervalo de data quanto do cliente procurado?
Se entendi corretamente então vc precisa trocar por "OR" apenas:
SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE cliente LIKE '%Aarco%' OR (data_emissao <= '15-01-2017' OR data_emissao IS NULL)
Mas no resultado esperado da sua pergunta não é isso que da a entender.

Comment: @olavooneto podemos continuar essa discussão no chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54701/como-realizar-consulta-com-base-em-valor-null

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais direta e óbvia que consegui pensar pro seu problema foi usando um `IF`. Se `data_emissao` não for nulo e se `data_emissao` for menor que a data fornecida ou se `data_emissao` for nulo.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  nfe
WHERE
  cliente
  LIKE '%Aarco%'
  AND IF(data_emissao<>NULL, (data_emissao<='15-01-2017'), TRUE)
```

No caso, como você quer com um OR, podemos usar

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  nfe
WHERE
  cliente
  LIKE '%Aarco%'
  AND ((data_emissao IS NOT NULL AND data_emissao<='15-01-2017') OR data_emissao IS NULL)
```